# Tokyo Late Night/Early Morning Layover

Tags: layovers, tokyo

I am travelling to and from Jakarta (from the US) this December, and have long layovers both ways through Tokyo (changing airports).

Layover #1 - 13 hrs, need to switch airport from Narita to Haneda. Lands 8:30pm, departs at 10am.
Layover #2 - 12 hrs, need to switch airport from Haneda to Narita. Lands at 11pm, departs at 11am.

Both layover lands on a Friday, out on a Saturday. Taking into consideration time for immigration, customs, baggage, and travel to/from the airports, I figured, we'll have about 6 hours to wonder around Tokyo. A good bit of that time will be in the late night/early morning part of the day. Assuming we don't land and want to immediately pass out, is there anything to go see or do, say around 2 am in Tokyo?

Definitely have eyes set on Tsukiji Market. EDIT: *Any other ideas of things to do between midnight and 6am in Tokyo?* Figured I'd give crowd sourcing a try :)

Thanks!

Comment: Wow those are tough layovers. purely one opinion, I would just go direct to the other airport, stay at a cheap airport hotel (you'll only have a few hours) and then take off the next morning! If you do want to wander around Tokyo all night, Alban has given the perfect answer! (Would it be possible to change your ticket and stay a whole day in Tokyo?  Awesome opportunity.)

Comment: Yeah, if I wanted to go to Tokyo would be ~$1500 just the flight there... Enjoy!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Layover #1 - 13 hrs, need to switch airport from Narita to Haneda. Lands 8:30pm, departs at 10am.

It will take 60-90 minutes to get out of Narita, the express trains will have stopped running by then. Regular trains and buses run until about 11pm which gives you an hour to figure the buses out.

> Layover #2 - 12 hrs, need to switch airport from Haneda to Narita. Lands at 11pm, departs at 11am.

It will take 60-90 minutes to get out of Haneda, the trains will have stopped running by then. But Haneda is a short taxi ride from central Tokyo so less of a problem.

I would recommend that you book a room at each airport - any arrival delays will mean you will be too late to get into Tokyo. Transportation starts very early in the morning, you won't have any problems getting to the other airport.

Central Tokyo to Haneda is about an hour, you will need to be there at least 90 minutes before departure.

Central Tokyo (or Haneda) to Narita is 2 hours. And you need to be at Narita at least 2 hours before your flight. So that means checking out of your hotel at 6am, latest.

Published times of 55 minutes to Narita are platform-to-platform times of a limited express train that runs twice an hour.

Comment: For layover #1, do you think a train ride into Narita (the city) and checking out the Friday night life would be worthwhile?

Answer (score 2):

How many days do you have? :) It really depends on your tastes

On [this](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/english/tv/tokyoeye/archives2013.html) site from the NHK TV of Japan, you have a program which only discusses Tokyo, and I see it here in Portugal, so you can imagine it has plenty of info :) :)

You can try the Akihabara district for electronic stuff, the night life of the Shibuya district...

But if you want a guide, try [this](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3060.html) which will tell you where you need to go in every hour.

Hope this helps you :) Happy Tokyoing

Comment: Yup, Tokyo Eye, the greatest show on TV!

Comment: Wish I could see it more often... My SP doesn't allow me to record it anymore...